# Call the backing bean onclick of ice:pannelTab

Tags: jsf, icefaces

Can we call the backing bean, onclick of the ice:pannelTab ?
I tried something like this. It calls the backing bean, but doesn't change the tab.

```
onclick="#{backing.onClick}; return false;"

public String getOnClick(){
     //...
     return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

onclick is a client side callback, it is used to execute javascript methods, for server side operation you should consider using an ajax listener component like `f:ajax`

Comment: I found out a better option. There is a tabChangedListener event for do that :)